# Google Sheets: Split data and delete first part of each new cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm feeding data from a SAAS into a Google Sheet, and would need to format it a bit to be able to work with it.

Most columns are ok, but one column has multiple parameters in one. Each cell looks like (data anonymized):

```
affiliate_fees: None
affiliate_percent: 0.X
amount_refunded: 0
author_fees: 0
author_id: xxxx
author_percent: 0.5
coupon_id: xxxx
created_at: 2016-xxxxx
currency: USD
custom_gateway?: None
earnings_usd: None
meta: {u'url': None, u'class': u'transaction', u'image_url': None, u'description': None, u'name': u'xxxx'}
net_charge: xxx
net_charge_usd: xxx
paypal_payment_id: PAY-XXXXXXX
purchased_at: 2016-xxxx
refundable: True
sale_id: xxxx
status: None
stripe_charge_token: None
stripe_invoice_id: None
total_fedora_fee: None
total_processor_fee: None
user_id: xxxx
vat_fees: None
```

I've already found out how to `SPLIT` the data into different columns - I'm doing it via `=SPLIT(CC2,CHAR(10))`

Now what I'd like to do, ideally in the same operation, is to remove the part before the first colon `:`

So the goal is: ending up with only the values (part after the `:`) spread into different columns. I can manually enter the column names. For examaple:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| affiliate_fees       | affiliate_percent       |
--------------------------------------------------
| None                 | 0.X                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| ...                  | ...                     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Any hints? Thanks for your time!

*Note: I don't really need the `meta:` line, it can be discarded. I just left it in there because it might (or might not?) make things extra tricky*

Comment: Do not combine [tag:excel] and [tag:google-spreadsheet] as they don't have the same set of built-in functions, i.e. split function isn't available in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative 1

Google Sheets introduced few months ago "Split text to columns" as a menu command. See [Separate cell text into columns](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6325535?hl=en) for further details.

Once you separate the text, you could use copy & paste > transpose

## Alternative 2

A single formula alternative is to use

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A25,{"(.*[\w\?])+\:","\: (.*)+"})))
```

This will return an 25 x 2 array, and you will not have to manually add the column headers.

## Alternative 3

If you still want to use [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en), you could use `": "` as the separator and FALSE as the third argument to threat them as a single separator, but this also will split the `meta: ...` into several columns.

Assume that your data start at A1, then the formula to use is:

```
=SPLIT(A1,": ",FALSE)
```

To include all the rows with data, you will have to fill down this formula. Then do copy & paste > transpose.

Answer (score 0):

In [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EvF-N6CHN8-G-6SalJGNphgtcfPLnXicaNmCWz4si24/edit?usp=sharing) I used this formula in cell E2

```
=ArrayFormula({regexreplace(split(A3, char(10)), "\:(.+)",""); regexreplace(split(A3, char(10)), "(.+)\: ","")})
```

This will create a row with headers and the values in row 2. If you don't want the headers, just use

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(split(A3, char(10)), "(.+)\: ",""))
```

See if that works for you ?